# Superfish Main Menu not filling block vertically

Tags: drupal-7, menubar, superfish

I am using Superfish with the Drupal 7 At Commerce theme (Adaptive Themes).

The main menu is not displaying properly.  The menu is only filling the upper half of the Main Menu Block as provided by the theme.  Also, the menu items are crunched together too closely.

The image shows the menu, at only half its vertical size with menu items crunched together.

I have used this theme with superfish before and never had to do any special styling.

I think I am missing something or have not configured something correctly.

I appreciate any help.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It is in the theme/sub-theme.  It turns out that the minor version of the theme and sub-theme must match.  I reinstalled both and the problem went away.